# Pagination Problems(PHP superglobal variable issue, undefined index)

Tags: php

i am trying to implement pagination somewhere and i have this issue:

I have this part to change links:

```
echo " <a href='$_SERVER[SCRIPT_NAME]?Page=$Prev_Page'><< Back</a> ";
```

which gives this error for this part:

```
$Page = $_GET["Page"];  
if(!$_GET["Page"])  
{
```

It says undefined index..
Why do I get this Error?
Thanks

Comment: ```if(!isset($_GET['Page'])) {```
check whether page is set, your variant expects page to be set already

Comment: What is the exact question?

Comment: Instead of `<<` use `&lt;&lt;` to prevent confusion of broken tags

Comment: Maybe it's not set! check with     if(isset($_GET["Page"]))

Comment: Luceos thanks, this resolves the first part, but i still get index undefined for : $Page = $_GET["Page"];

Answer (score 3):

You should quote the array index. also use html entities.
Like this

```
echo " <a href='{$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']}?Page=$Prev_Page'>&lt;&lt; Back</a> ";
```

And its safe to check if `$_GET["Page"]` exists.

```
$Page = isset($_GET["Page"]) ? $_GET["Page"]: false;
```

Comment: Not quoting the array key will just throw a warning.  You should still do this, but it's not the issue here.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because you are missing an index in the array. $_GET is just an array, so you should check if the key exists first.

```
$Page = (array_key_exists('page', $_GET)) ? $_GET["page"] : false;  
if($Page===false)  
{  
   //no page
   return;
}
```

Comment: Exellent, this solved it quick :)
thank you, i'm accepting it in a few minutes!

Comment: Thanks for the downvote. I realy hated that +2, like the round number :)

Answer (score 0):

```
// empty() works even if the variable doesn't exist, kind of like isset()
if(!empty($_GET['Page']) !== false) {
    // Do stuff
    $page = $_GET['Page'];
}
```

Comment: be careful with empty. it also returns false if Page=0 and you might want to accept that http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

Comment: Yw, but your edit created the same problem as Ozi has. You are checking $_GET['Page'] before you know the key is there

Comment: I'm pretty sure it works though. The second part of the `if` only runs if the first part returns true, which will only happen if `$_GET['page']` not empty.

Comment: Ah yeah you are correct. It wont give the syntax error. But since empty will return false on 0, it wont get to the second part either.

Comment: Another nice try, but you are still running into the same problem if page=0 > `!empty(0) !== false` == `!true !== false` == `false !== false` == `false` so in the end you made a more complicated false statement. You should just use isset(), like you mention in your comment

Comment: I'm not quite sure why it doesn't work, and your explanation doesn't make much sense to me. Triple equal signs should compare variable types as well, right? (=== or !==) So, unless `empty()` returns an integer (0) it should work. Am i missing something? See: http://goo.gl/LctyC

Comment: Empty doesnt return integer(0), it returns a boolean, no matter what the content of the var is that goes in.

Comment: I just re-read your explanation and it makes total sense now. My bad!